# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I am creating pdf file using iTextSharp.pdf and iTextSharp.Text below is my code

```
 string source = "G:/F2290_2016_EFORM2290.pdf";
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(source);

            PdfStamper stmp = new PdfStamper(reader, new
            FileStream("G:/F2290_2016_EFORM2290.pdf", FileMode.Create));
            AcroFields form = stmp.AcroFields;
            IDictionary<string, AcroFields.Item> fs = form.Fields;
            foreach (var f in fs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(f.Key);
            }
```

Here I am getting error

```
 PdfStamper stmp = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream("G:/F2290_2016_EFORM2290.pdf", FileMode.Create));
```

Error is **The process cannot access the file 'G:\F2290_2016_EFORM2290.pdf' because it is being used by another process.**

Comment: If the readers/writers - (e.g. anything that opens a file) implement `IDisposable` (which they probably should), use a `using` block to automatically clean-up when out-of-scope. e.g. `using(var stream = new FileStream(xyz...)) { // Do stuff }`. This way you won't forget to dispose.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you are opening a new Pdfreader `PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(source);` and then a new FileStream on the same source `...new FileStream("G:/F2290_2016_EFORM2290.pdf", FileMode.Create)`.

Answer (score 0):

this is a duplicate of [itextsharp not closing files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574993/itextsharp-not-closing-files)

close your VS for now, restart IIS, whatever it needs to free up the file once, and then your code should close the pdfreader in a finally block so that the file gets closed.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: you're running on a Windows OS

Why are you using a forward slash (/)? Also if you use the correct diurectory separator character for Windows () then you'll need to escape it correctly, either by using a double backslash (\) or a verbatim string.

Next, make sure that no other application has the PDF file open, and also use a different c'tor - try [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h0z48dh(v=vs.110).aspx) for size

Lastly, you mention it's a web application, make sure that the site is running in a context that has permissions to write to G: and that it can see it (i.e. it's not a network drive mapped for one specific user)